# Using foreach with a variable which may NOT be an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

**So, here's my situation :**

I'm getting some input stored in a variable (`$keywords`).
This variable may either be a string (=1 keyword) - like `"banana"`, or it may be an array (=multiple keywords) - like `array ("banana","apple","mango")`.

This is the way I'm using it :

```
foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
{
    // do sth with $keyword
}
```

**This works fine when `$keyword` is an array**, but when it's not I'm getting errors. (quite obviously)

What would be the most efficient workaround, to avoid errors, while keeping my `foreach` structure as-is?

---

This is what I've thought of (to put before the loop), but I don't really like it :

```
if (count($keywords)==1) $keywords = array($keywords);
```

---

**UPDATE :** Guys, I *know* about `is_array`. My point was to do it as elegantly as possible, without adding  block of code or creating a mess with `switch` or `if`/`else` statements, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply cast the variable to array:

```
$keywords = (array) $keywords;
```

if the variable is an array no thing will happen , otherwise it will be transformed to an array :
so 
`1` will be `array(1)`
AND
`'keyword'` will be `array('keyword')`

Comment: Fabulously simple; 7 answers (so far) and only **you** got the very essence of my question. Thanks a lot, buddy!

Comment: Gj, deleted my answer for this ;)

Comment: Was just writing a similar thing when i saw this, +1.

Comment: Yeah, totally beat my (deleted) answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($keywords) && !is_array($keywords)) { $keywords = Array($keywords); }
else if (!isset($keywords)) { $keywords = Array(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the is_array command: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Answer (score 0):

use the php [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) built-in function

```
if(is_array($keywords))
foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
{
    // do sth with $keyword
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$type = gettype($keywords);
switch ($type)
{
    case "string":
       // do what you need with string
       break;
    case "array":
       foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
       {
           // do smth when is array
       }
       break;
}
```

Check for type, my solution allows You to check wether is string, array or other type, which You may specify if needed.
In simplier solution, use `if (is_array($keywords);`

Comment: OP wants to convert the string to an array to use it in the foreach loop - your solution would break after converting it and make no use of the loop.